# "How can I access the size property in the fileFilter function, e.g., file.size?

Tags: javascript, express, multer

```
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        console.log(file.size) //undefined
        if (file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'multipart/form-data') {
            cb(null, true)
        } else {
            cb(new InvariantError('error'), false)
        }
    },
    limits: {
        fileSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024,
        files: 3
    }
})
```

I want to conditionally handle errors in the **`fileFilter`** so that even if I send a request multiple times, files that exceed the limit are not uploaded into memory, even if an error message is displayed. I would like to use the **`size`** property in the **`fileFilter`**, maybe I can create conditions to ensure that each file does not exceed the limit. but when i `console.log(file.size)` the output was undefined